# AngularJS Дублируются картики

Tags: angularjs

```
<div class="rowData ng-scope" ng-repeat="event in items">
<a ng-click="showImg = !showImg; image(event)">Show images</a>
<div ng-show="showImg">
<img ng-click="nextImage()" ng-src="{{ current.filename }}" height="450" width="550"/>
</div>
</div>
```

`Items` содержит json:

```
{name: "Ivan", number: "89269269696", listfile:Array(4)
0: {filename: "userivan.jpg"}
1: {filename: "userivan2.jpg"}
2: {filename: "userivan3.jpg"}
3: {filename: "userivan4.jpg"}
}

{name: "Valeriy", number: "89209209090", listfile:Array(5)
0: {filename: "photovaleriy.jpg"}
1: {filename: "uservaleriy2.jpg"}
2: {filename: "uservaleriy3.jpg"}
3: {filename: "uservaleriy4.jpg"}
4: {filename: "uservaleriy5.jpg"}
}
и т.д.

$scope.image = function (event) {
                $scope.image = [];
                path = "/image/";
                $scope.image = event.listfile.map(el=>({"filename": path +el.filename}));
                $scope.current = $scope.image[0];
        }
```

После чего `$scope.image` содержит список фото того или иного пользователя, например:

```
0: {filename: "/image/photovaleriy.jpg"}
1: {filename: "/image/uservaleriy2.jpg"}
2: {filename: "/image/uservaleriy3.jpg"}
3: {filename: "/image/uservaleriy4.jpg"}
4: {filename: "/image/uservaleriy5.jpg"}

$scope.nextImage = function () {
if($scope.currentIdx < $scope.image.length-1) {
$scope.currentIdx++;
} else {
$scope.currentIdx = 0;
}
$scope.current = $scope.image[$scope.currentIdx];
}
```

Суть в том, что если открывать список фотографий следующего пользователя, 
не закрыв фото прежнего, у всех пользователей начнут отображаться одинаковые фотографии:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите разобраться, почему так выходит!

Comment: что значит открыть список не закрыв фото? ой-вэй, не стоит использовать имя _event_ для своей переменной, это может вводить в заблуждение

Comment: строка `$scope.image = [];` ненужна. А еще обрати внимание, что ты этому свойству присваиваешь функцию, а потом меняешь на массив

Comment: В общем, делай [mcve] - без этого непонятно как у тебя код вообще работает